# Add Total Sum column that skips certain columns

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I have a table where for certain customers, there is a code to indicate who it is, and then the full name of the customer, and then the total sales they completed with the total revenue.

| Customer Code | Customer Name | Total Sales | Total Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | 2 | 11 |
| ghi | jkl | 1 | 20 |
| mno | pqr | 7 | 6 |
| stu | vwx | 5 | 9 |

I want to add a row at the bottom that creates a total of all the sales and all the revenue, and skips over first two columns to create a "Total" single column/row. See below:

[image]

I was able to create the desired row using SQL however it did not follow the formatting that I desired. The data is being read in through a sql server and formatted using pandas and df .

EDIT: I do not know what is meant by the presentation layer. I need that bottom row to have that bottom row with the TOTAL being exactly centered and cutting between the first two columns. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, this normally something for your presentation layer.

Comment: Presentation layer is the software you display the data in. No one who uses your database data should be accessing it via SSMS... you either use an app or reporting services or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this is typically something you would solve at the presentation layer, however, you can use WITH ROLLUP to achieve your result set:

```
DECLARE @Sales TABLE (CustomerCode NVARCHAR(3), CustomerName NVARCHAR(3), TotalSales INT, TotalRevenue INT)
INSERT INTO @Sales (CustomerCode, CustomerName, TotalSales, TotalRevenue) VALUES
('abc', 'def', 2, 11),
('ghi', 'jkl', 1, 20),
('mno', 'pqr', 7, 6 ),
('stu', 'vwx', 5, 9 )

SELECT CustomerCode, COALESCE(CustomerName,'TOTAL') AS CustomerName, TotalSales, TotalRevenue
  FROM (
        SELECT CustomerCode, CustomerName, SUM(TotalSales) AS TotalSales, SUM(TotalRevenue) AS TotalRevenue
          FROM @Sales
         GROUP BY CustomerCode, CustomerName WITH ROLLUP
       ) a
 WHERE a.CustomerName IS NOT NULL
    OR (
            a.CustomerCode IS NULL 
        AND a.CustomerName IS NULL
       )
```

```
CustomerCode    CustomerName    TotalSales  TotalRevenue
--------------------------------------------------------
abc             def             2           11
ghi             jkl             1           20
mno             pqr             7           6
stu             vwx             5           9
NULL            TOTAL           15          46
```

Comment: @DaleK At the request of some higher officials in my job it needed to be formatted the way I showcased, I did not have much say. I was also able to do the above solution by appending a new row to the bottom in python but I never found out how to change the formatting of the table style to do what I needed